# How does this array work

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
void main()
{int v[100],n,k;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>v[i];
   k=0;
   for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
      if(v[i]==v[i-1]) k++;
      cout<<k;}
```

Hey guys, I'm quite new to arrays and was wondering if someone could tell me what this line of code is doing:

```
int v[100],n,k;
```

If I'm right in my understanding, I am assuming that we are declaring a array with `100` possible values. However, what is `n` and `k` doing here? I saw a similar piece of code before, and it looked like it was programmed in a way such that the value of k would be inserted into our array `n` number of times.

Is my understanding there correct? I know what the rest of the code is doing but it's just that one line that is confusing.

Comment: That's not a `vector`, that's an *array* of 100 `int`s.

Comment: Modified the question to refer to it as a array then, thanks

Comment: probably you understand better if they were written as int v[100]; int n; int k; ?

Comment: Why don't you read about variable declarations rules?

Comment: @JimmyK change cin>>n to cin>>n; n=n<(sizeof v /sizeof *v)?n:(sizeof v /sizeof *v);  //so even user write 1000 on cin it be limited to array size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `v` is an array of `int`, while `n` and `k` are simple variables ([scalars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computing%29)) of type `int`.

It's just a shorthand for:

```
int v[100];
int n;
int k;
```

Comment: Oh derp, indeed that makes more sense now. Just going to try and work the question out in my head now and if it makes sense will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now, will mark this as the answer! Part of the confusion was thinking that this was a vector, so I thought n and k had something to do with declaring vectors. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may declare severeal variables with the same declare spesifiers in one line. For example

```
int width, height;
```

Here there are two variables that are declared as having type int. You can also include an array declarator in the same line.

```
int width, height, sizes[100];
```

Here there are three variables, width, height, sizes, that are declared. Variable sizes is declared as an array.

It is equivalent to

```
int width;
int height;
int sizes[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

`v` is an array with 100 elements.
`n` is the number of elements to look through (probably in the range [0, 100] or we'll run into out of bounds problems trying to accessing v[n] when n > 100)
`k` is used to count the number of times a value in `v` is equal to the next value in `v`.

So lets take an example in some kind of pseudo-code:

```
 v = {0,3,3, ..., n};
 // lets for simplicity say that n=3 (i.e. the number of integers I specified)
 // the loop will run from 0 to n=3 both the outer and inner loop mind you..
```

The outer loop starts, `i=0`, `k` is set to zero because at this point we don't have any hits.

we start second loop with `i=1` (no need to check `i=0` since we don't want to check an entry against itself). And every time `v[0]` is equal to any of the other numbers in the set we will add one to `k`, so for our example: `0 != 3` and `0!=3` and `k=0` will be the case, the program will print `0` and move on.

Second iteration `i=1` and `v[i] = 3`. And the second loop starts to check `v[1]` against `v[2]` in this case both happen to be three and so `k` become one. and the iteration is done. the value `1` is printed and the loop continues.. and so it goes.

I would like to mention as well that the inner loop is creating a local variable `int i=1;` in the for-loop, I would be a bit careful with that since there might be compilers which can't scope it correctly and choose a different name for the loop index variable of the inner loop, traditionally one might use `j` but well both `i` and `j` could be argued to be bad names, but it's another discussion.

I hope it clears things up a bit.